# Как используя AdminService получить информацию о приложениях на WebSphere?

Tags: java, java-ee, websphere

У меня есть adminService

```
private com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminService adminService = AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService();
```

С помощью него я могу получать разную информацию о сервере, но не могу получить информацию об установленных приложениях(имена, статус запущен или нет и др.), думаю нужно использовать метод invoke, но исходя из документации не оч понятно как это сделать:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminService.html

Подобных примеров на просторах интернета я не нашел, подскажите пожалуйста, кто что знает по этому поводу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужен AdminClient

```
Properties connectProps = new Properties();
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, CONNECTOR_HOST);
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, port);
if (credentialsRequired) {
    connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, userName);
    connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, password);
}
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);
String query = "WebSphere:*,type=J2EEApplication,j2eeType=J2EEApplicationtype=J2EEApplication,j2eeType=J2EEApplication";
ObjectName queryName = new ObjectName(query);
Set appObjectNames = adminClient.queryNames(queryName, null);
for (Object obj : appObjectNames) {
  ObjectName appObjectName = (ObjectName) obj;
  String appName = appObjectName.getKeyProperty("J2EEName");
}
```